# Finding smallest value in an array most efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays

There are N values in the array, and one of them is the smallest value. How can I find the smallest value most efficiently?

Comment: why you consider minimum iterations?, it is just 8 elements, even your algorithm will be 8 iterations O(n) in all cases

Comment: I need the best algorithm here to resolve this kind of situation, the number of elements can increased.......

Comment: this question is asked in interview...

Comment: if it is a random array, you can't to much better than O(n)

Comment: Seriously? An interview? Even answering this raises ethical dilemmas.

Comment: @Mike: Presumably Muhammad is not currently in the interview.  8-)

Comment: @RichieHindle: Still. It scares me ^^

Comment: That's a pretty basic question from someone who is Software Engineer(Team Lead).

Comment: I don't see why answering the question would be scary when you can find the answer easily with a google search. If it's an interview question, what the heck is the job?

Comment: If you can find the answer easily with a google search, should it really be on StackOverflow?

Comment: I think it's a pretty good interview question, because the obvious solution is the best, but it may make one wonder....

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, StackOverflow is for questions of any difficulty, even if it can be googled.

Comment: @slypete: if the array is sorted, first element will be smallest, so no need of iteration :)

Comment: @GMan: I have not edit this post, I am tryhing to delete this post, I am unable to delete this post, So I have rollback it...

Comment: Why would you try to delete it? :) This is good knowledge for people with similar questions. And as far as I know, you cannot delete it.

Comment: There is about once chance in a million that they are asking for the Dijkstra Linear Search Theorem, but I thought I'd better mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If they are unsorted, you can't do much but look at each one, which is O(N), and when you're done you'll know the minimum.

---

Pseudo-code:

```
small = <biggest value> // such as std::numerical_limits<int>::max
for each element in array:
    if (element < small)
        small = element
```

A better way reminded by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38924/ben) to me was to just initialize small with the first element:

```
small = element[0]
for each element in array, starting from 1 (not 0):
    if (element < small)
        small = element
```

The above is wrapped in the [algorithm](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/start) header as [std::min_element](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/min_element).

---

If you can keep your array sorted as items are added, then finding it will be O(1), since you can keep the smallest at front.

That's as good as it gets with arrays.

Comment: okay finding element will be O(1) but keeping the array sorted will cost more (depend on your sorting algorithm)

Comment: which may be OK if you need to know the smallest value quickly and you're not adding new elements all the time.

Comment: Note that "small = element[0]" is unsafe if the array might be empty.

Comment: True. What is the standard convention of finding the minimum (maxmimum, etc) of an empty container? I don't imagine you can really return anything useful aside from a max value, which might not exist for user-defined types.

Comment: You should return null for an empty container.

Comment: If its double/float you could return NaN

Comment: I just looked up what min_element does, and it just initializes it in the second style and if start == end, returns that result. In other words, it returns end.

Answer (score 8):

You need too loop through the array, remembering the smallest value you've seen so far.  Like this:

```
int smallest = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would initialize smallest with the first element of the array then iterate from 1 to array_length. BTW you forgot i in int i = 0;

Comment: @Ben: Just remember to deal with the case where the array is empty.  8-)

Answer (score 8):

The stl contains a bunch of methods that should be used dependent to the problem.

```
std::find
std::find_if
std::count
std::find
std::binary_search
std::equal_range
std::lower_bound
std::upper_bound
```

Now it contains on your data what algorithm to use.
This [Artikel](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/CUJ_Dec_2001.pdf) contains a perfect table to help choosing the right algorithm.

---

In the special case where min max should be determined and you are using std::vector or ???* array

```
std::min_element
std::max_element
```

can be used.

Comment: Why evoke all these algorithms and not std::min_element, which is the one asked for in the question?

Comment: Just because I din't know it. But its always O(N) if you know more about the data or your data isn't stored in an unsorted vector you get more performance using other algorithms.
I think the mentioned articel shows that the question for the best algorithm always depends on the data and the container.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be really efficient and you have enough time to spent, use SIMD instruction.

You can compare several pairs in one instruction:

```
r0 := min(a0, b0)
r1 := min(a1, b1)
r2 := min(a2, b2)
r3 := min(a3, b3)
__m64 _mm_min_pu8(__m64 a , __m64 b );
```

Today every computer supports it. Other already have written min function for you:

http://smartdata.usbid.com/datasheets/usbid/2001/2001-q1/i_minmax.pdf

or use already ready [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981787/good-portable-simd-library).

Answer (score 4):

If the array is sorted in ascending or descending order then you can find it with complexity O(1).
For an array of ascending order the first element is the smallest element, you can get it by arr[0] (0 based indexing).
If the array is sorted in descending order then the last element is the smallest element,you can get it by arr[sizeOfArray-1].

If the array is not sorted then you have to iterate over the array to get the smallest element.In this case time complexity is O(n), here n is the size of array.

```
int arr[] = {5,7,9,0,-3,2,3,4,56,-7};
int smallest_element=arr[0] //let, first element is the smallest one

for(int i =1;i<sizeOfArray;i++)  
{
    if(arr[i]<smallest_element)
    {
     smallest_element=arr[i];
    }
}
```

You can calculate it in input section (when you have to find smallest element from a given array)

```
int smallest_element;
int arr[100],n;
cin>>n;
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
cin>>arr[i];
if(i==0)
{
    smallest_element=arr[i]; //smallest_element=arr[0];
}
else if(arr[i]<smallest_element)
{
smallest_element = arr[i];
}
}
```

Also you can get smallest element by built in function

```
#inclue<algorithm>
int smallest_element = *min_element(arr,arr+n); //here n is the size of array
```

You can get smallest element of any range by using this function
such as,

```
int arr[] = {3,2,1,-1,-2,-3};
cout<<*min_element(arr,arr+3); //this will print 1,smallest element of first three element
cout<<*min_element(arr+2,arr+5); // -2, smallest element between third and fifth element (inclusive)
```

I have used asterisk (*), before min_element() function. Because it returns pointer of smallest element.
All codes are in c++.
You can find the maximum element in opposite way.

Answer (score 1):

Richie's answer is close. It depends upon the language. Here is a good solution for java:

```
int smallest =  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int array[]; // Assume it is filled.
int array_length = array.length;
for (int i = array_length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = array[i];
    }
}
```

I go through the array in reverse order, because comparing "i" to "array_length" in the loop comparison requires a fetch and a comparison (two operations), whereas comparing "i" to "0" is a single JVM bytecode operation. If the work being done in the loop is negligible, then the loop comparison consumes a sizable fraction of the time.

Of course, others pointed out that encapsulating the array and controlling inserts will help. If getting the minimum was ALL you needed, keeping the list in sorted order is not necessary. Just keep an instance variable that holds the smallest inserted so far, and compare it to each value as it is added to the array. (Of course, this fails if you remove elements. In that case, if you remove the current lowest value, you need to do a scan of the entire array to find the new lowest value.)

Comment: "It depends upon the language. Here is a good solution for java" Why even post this, along with JVM information, in a C++ question?

Comment: However, if the array is large, going through the array in forward order might result in faster memory access due to cache memory effects.

Answer (score 0):

An O(1) sollution might be to just guess: The smallest number in your array will often be 0. 0 crops up everywhere. Given that you are only looking at unsigned numbers. But even then: 0 is good enough. Also, looking through all elements for the smallest number is a real pain. Why not just use 0? It could actually be the correct result!

If the interviewer/your teacher doesn't like that answer, try 1, 2 or 3. They also end up being in most homework/interview-scenario numeric arrays...

**On a more serious side:** How often will you need to perform this operation on the array? Because the sollutions above are all O(n). If you want to do that m times to a list you will be adding new elements to all the time, why not pay some time up front and create a heap? Then finding the smallest element can really be done in O(1), without resulting to cheating.

Comment: You do not have to create a heap on your own. Use a std::set which defines an sorting order.

Comment: I'm sure there was a heapify (or similar) function in the stl... Is it wise to count on std::set's sorting order?

Comment: YOu don't have to count on it. Just provide an own one :-)

Comment: Yes, set is sorted. However, there are heap functions that you can use.

Comment: There is even no need to use an expensive set. Just use an array wrapper with an automatically updated `min` variable on insert.

Answer (score 0):

If finding the minimum is a one time thing, just iterate through the list and find the minimum.

If finding the minimum is a very common thing and you only need to operate on the minimum, use a Heap data structure.

A heap will be faster than doing a sort on the list but the tradeoff is you can only find the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing some kind of your own array abstraction, you can get O(1) if you store smallest added value in additional attribute and compare it every time a new item is put into array.

It should look something like this:

```
class MyArray
{
public:
    MyArray() : m_minValue(INT_MAX) {}

    void add(int newValue)
    {
        if (newValue < m_minValue) m_minValue = newValue;
        list.push_back( newValue );
    }

    int min()
    {
        return m_minValue;
    }

private:
    int m_minValue;
    std::list m_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//find the min in an array list of #s
$array = array(45,545,134,6735,545,23,434);

$smallest = $array[0];
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++){
    if($array[$i] < $smallest){
        echo $array[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                //smalest number in the array//
    double small = x[0];
    for(t=0;t<x[t];t++)
    {
         if(x[t]<small)
             {
                small=x[t];
            }
    }
    printf("\nThe smallest number is  %0.2lf  \n",small);
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Procedure:

We can use [min_element(array, array+size)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) function . But it iterator
that return the address of minimum element . If we use [*min_element(array, array+size)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) then it will return the minimum value of array.

---

### C++ implementation

```
  #include<bits/stdc++.h>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
     int num;
     cin>>num;
     int arr[10];

     for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
     {
       cin>>arr[i];
     }


    cout<<*min_element(arr,arr+num)<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I think , it is the best process to find the smallest number.

Answer (score -1):

```
int small=a[0];
for (int x: a.length)
{
    if(a[x]<small)
        small=a[x];
}
```

Comment: your answer would be more meaningful if you would add some comments explaining why this is an efficient way to find the smallest value.

Comment: There are many other equivalent answers to this question.  Your answer doesn't really add much.

Answer (score -1):

### C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int arr[n] = {12,4,15,6,2};
    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if (min>arr[i]){
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << min;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient, uses a non-standard header, bad practice using directive, non-standard feature (VLA), and doesn't add anything new to the existing answers