# Finding smallest value in an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function to find the smallest value in an array, but i cannot figure out the error i have made. Can someone take a look at it? thanks!!!

```
void smallest(int array[],int size)
    {
        int smallest=array[0];
            for (int i=1;i<size-1;i++)
                {
                if (array[i]<smallest)

                 smallest=array[i];

                }
        cout<<smallest<<'\n';

     }
```

the code are not executed because there is breakpoint, and I cannot see where is the problem.

Comment: Use a debugger to locate the "breakpoint" in your code. Check the values of all involved variables, and make sure they are valid. And *please* try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, that show us how you use and call this function and with what values.

Comment: `< size-1` surely that should just be `< size`

Comment: do you have stack trace

Comment: also, if the array is zero size, your program will crash

Comment: @SvenNilsson I only know about nullptr but I haven't heard about array of zero size, is it the new feature?

Comment: @Danh: It's not new feature. By standard those are not allowed, but there is a special case when it is useful and therefore it can be implemented (but definetely shouldn't except for this one case). There is plenty information about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)

Comment: One liner -- `#include <algorithm>... std::cout << *std::min_element(array, array + size) << '\n'`;

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Even if it's a flexible array member, its actual size will not be zero, from standard: `If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.` and for VLA or FAM: `the behavior is undefined if the expression's value is less than or equal to zero`. In this question, the function parameter is indeed a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more efficient solution here: 
[Finding smallest value in an array most efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042507/finding-smallest-value-in-an-array-most-efficiently).

Code snippet:

```
int smallest = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not different from the question asked

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not going to the last element of your array. You should remove the minus 1 of the condition. And do not hesitate to the test the value of the received arguments:

```
void smallest(int array[], int size)
{
    if (size <= 0 || !array)
        return;
    int smallest = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++)
        if (array[i] < smallest)
            smallest = array[i];
    cout << smallest << '\n';
}
```