# Best C++ Matrix Library for sparse unitary matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, lapack, umfpack

I am looking for a good (in the best case actively maintained) C++ matrix library. Thereby it should be templated, because I want to use a complex of rationals as numerical type. The matrices what I am dealing with are mainly sparse and unitary.

Can you please suggest libraries and also give a small explaination why to use them, because I know  how to find them, but I cannot really decide what is suitable for me because I am missing the experience with them.

EDIT:

The main operations I am dealing with are *matrix multiplication*, *scalar multiplication with a vector* and *kronecker product*. The size of the matrices is exponential and I wanna at least be able to deal with matrices up to 1024x1024 entries.

Comment: What do you need the matrix library for? Basic linear algebra, solvers, or ...? How big are your matrices?

Comment: Most of the time I am doing matrix multiplication, scalar multiplication and use the kronecker product. The matrices can be quite bit, at least I wanna be able to deal with 1024x1024 matrices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many people doing "serious" matrix stuff, rely on [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/), adding [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) / [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) (normal matrices) or [UMFPACK](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/) (sparse matrices) for more advanced math. The reason is that this code is well-tested, stable, reliable, and quite fast. Furthermore, you can buy them directly from a vendor (e.g. [Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/)) tuned towards your architecture, but also get them for free. [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) mentioned in [Manuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222549/best-c-matrix-library-for-sparse-unitary-matrices/2222589#2222589) is probably the standard C++ BLAS implementation. And if you need something like LAPACK later on, there are [bindings](http://mathema.tician.de/software/boost-bindings) to do so.

However, none of these standard libraries (BLAS / LAPACK / ATLAS or uBLAS + bindings + LAPACK / ATLAS) ticks your box for being templated and easy to use (unless uBLAS is all you'll ever need). Actually, I must admit, that I tend to call the C / Fortran interface directly when I use a BLAS / LAPACK implementation, since I often don't see much additional advantage in the uBLAS + bindings combination.

If I a need a simple-to-use, general-purpose C++ matrix library, I tend to use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (I used to use [NewMat](http://www.robertnz.net/nm_intro.htm) in the past). Advantages:

- quite fast on Intel architecture, probably the fastest for smaller matrices
- nice interface
- almost everything you expect from a matrix library
- you can easily add [new types](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#CustomScalarType)

Disadvantages (IMO):

- single-processor [**Edit:** partly fixed in [Eigen 3.0](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.0)]
- slower for larger matrices and some advanced math than ATLAS or Intel MKL (e.g. LU decomposition) [**Edit:** also improved in Eigen 3.0]
- only experimental support for sparse matrices [**Edit:** improved in upcoming version 3.1].

**Edit:** The upcoming Eigen 3.1 allows some functions to use the Intel MKL (or any other BLAS / LAPACK implementation).

Comment: One obvious advantage of a C++ wrapper is the performance gain provided by expression templates

Comment: @Manuel: agree. Avoiding temps is the main promise of matrix template libraries like http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/, http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/, etc. But you can do most of this in C code, too,  since BLAS routines do not copy matrices but work in-place where possible.

Comment: you can spare some temporaries by doing everything in place but there are other things that expression templates optimize. For example, in a C library if you do add(A, add(B, add(C, D))) then the intermediate results must be computed, and each step involves a loop, so in total you have 3 loops. With expression templates the result is only evaluated once: 1 loop.

Comment: Eigen seems to use right to left multiplication which is a bit strange.

Comment: uBLAS isn't a wrapper, it's wholly implemented in c++.

Comment: @rcollyer: thanks for your input. This was indeed wrongly worded. I am surprised that you are the first person to correct me on this error. The only apology I can give is that I have always used uBLAS in combination with the bindings (hence my "wrapper" perception), which (as mentioned) wasn't my favorite approach. But you are right -- and I should have remembered, because one of the reasons we opted against uBLAS was that uBLAS `prod` was substantially slower for larger dense matrices than ATLAS `gemm` (IIRC, Intel MKL overloads `prod` with `gemm` calls for this reason).

Comment: I've never used the wrapper functionality myself, as I rejected its use because I need access to the internal representation, nor could I figure out how to bolt on the functionality I needed. So, I went with codesourcery's VSIPL++ implementation.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), because it's passed the Boost filter.

There are a few template libs that support sparse matrices, so it's really hard to come up with a better rationale if you're not more specific about your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try [MLT](http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/) and [HASEM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hasem/) Matrix C++ Library. The last one is very well documented.